# Inventory slots are not creating in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-engine

Hi im unity and C# begginer and im doing inventory slot system and it has to create some number of inventory slots, **i put number 10 and its creating only 1 slot.**
When i save the code it gives me this warning:

**Assets\C# assets\Inventory Scripts\InventorySystem.cs(22,39): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement**
And this is my code (inventory holder):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

[System.Serializable]
public class InventoryHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] private int inventorySize;
   [SerializeField] protected InventorySystem inventorySystem;

   public InventorySystem InventorySystem => inventorySystem;

   public static UnityAction<InventorySystem> OnDynamicInventoryDisplayRequested;

   private void Awake()
  {
    inventorySystem = new InventorySystem(inventorySize);
  }
}
```

And InventorySystem code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Linq;

[System.Serializable]
public class InventorySystem
{
    [SerializeField] private List<InventorySlot> inventorySlots;

    public List<InventorySlot> InventorySlots => inventorySlots;
 
    public int InventorySize => InventorySlots.Count;

    public UnityAction<InventorySlot> OnInventorySlotChanged;

    public InventorySystem(int size)
    {
        inventorySlots = new List<InventorySlot>(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++);
    {
        inventorySlots.Add(new InventorySlot());
    }
 }

 public bool AddToInventory(InventoryItemData itemToAdd, int amountToAdd)
 {
     inventorySlots[0] = new InventorySlot(itemToAdd, amountToAdd);
     return true;
 }
```

}

Comment: Yes, the warning is because of the semi-colon at the end of this statement: `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++);`. You will execute `inventorySlots.Add(new InventorySlot())` exactly once, regardless of the value of `size` because the code that calls it is not in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your "for" loop is invalid.
Should be like that:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       inventorySlots.Add(new InventorySlot());
    }
```

Without the semi-colon after the "for" statement else it will not loop over  `inventorySlots.Add(new InventorySlot());`